# Black screen while installing?

Tags: system-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on a Acer Aspire V6 laptop with Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000 using a USB drive from Kingston. Booting from the USB I can see the purple screen for a few seconds then the screen goes black. I can still hear the Ubuntu login sound just no display.

Version trying to install: Ubuntu 13.10

What can be causing this/how can I fix it?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Try to simply increase the brightness through the keyboard.

In my new HP Envy 15 with Ubuntu the screen goes black at every start up, but if I increase the brightness through the keyboard everything goes back working

Comment: Will it be a problem that I have EUFI and Secure Boot on while running the install?